# create large a tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this tag: `<%= link_to 'Show', user_listing_url(listing.user, listing) %>` but instead of simply having it say 'Show' I actually want to place HTML inside of the `<a>` tag. Is this possible?

Example:

`<a href=""><div><div><img /></div></div></a>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can pass a block to [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

try something like this:

```
<%= link_to(user_listing_url(listing.user, listing)) do %>
  <div><div><img/></div></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I always forget you can do this. Upvoted and deleted my answer in favor of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I totally recommend marflar's answer above.

However I would add one comment which is that if you are using html elements within a `link_to` block this may apply rails default link styling which may not be desirable.

One alternative is to use a `button_to` link but don't forget the default method for this is POST so specify the options as GET:

```
button_to(user_listing_url(listing.user, listing), method: :get) do %> 
<div></div>
<% end %>
```